# Can you tell me what file is causing my backup to fail?

Tags: backup

I have my backups on automatic. And for the last two weeks I've been getting a popup notification just about every day with the following message:

```
Giving up after 5 attempts. ApiRequestError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1IXB2qdtDgDC7CtJ0fa9jS532u5GaO755?acknowledgeAbuse=false&alt=media returned "This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded">
```

I've tried looking at ~/.cache/deja-dup/duplicity.log and there is nothing appropriate there.